# Excel - VBA: Adressing and modifing a PowerPoint-Shape by Label-Name

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to change a shape in a Powerpoint from Excel, but I can't address it by name (label). Is there a trick?

In the presentation the slide is created by a master slide and this master slide has a rounded rectangle. This rectangle should be longer or shorter in the actual presentation (RGB-Colors). But I can not get it right. Could someone help me?

```
Sub createPPT()

    Dim oPPApp As Object, oPPPrsn As Object, oPPSlide As Object
    Dim oPPShape As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim PPTFieldname As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    FlName = "C:\testpraesentation.pptx"

    '~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oPPApp.Visible = msoTrue

    '~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
    Set oPPPrsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Open(FlName)
    '~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
    Set oPPSlide = oPPPrsn.Slides(3)
    '~~> Change this to the relevant shape
    Set oPPShape = oPPSlide.Shapes("Textfeld6")


    '~~> Write to the shape
    oPPShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
    Tabelle1.Range("A1").Value



    '''''''''''''''''''' 
    This is the part
    '''''''''''''''''''' 
    oPPSlide.Shapes("Säule8") Type:=msoShapeRoundedRectangle, _
    Left:=500, Top:=500, Width:=Tabelle1.Range("C6").Value, Height:=Tabelle1.Range("C7").Value
    
    '''''' END ''''''''
End Sub
```

Anyone?

xSodax

Comment: The program interface can give you a clue. Open the Selection Pane for that slide. Is the shape listed? If not then you can't access it using oPPSlide, because it doesn't exist on the slide. Please post whether you added the shape to the _Slide Master_ (the larger thumbnail at the top of the list in Slide Master view) or a _Slide Layout_ (the smaller thumbnails for Title Slide, Title and Content, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
tbh:Seems that I was just too overslept during my experiments: I did not save the PPT template at all.
No master, no slides, no renamed shapes...

will it try again. This time I concentrate better.